# Changing PDF font size in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, fonts, itext

Following is the function I am writing to create PDF using iTextSharp.

Let me explain the function ...

I am here creating a PDF file from the another Template PDF file. The template PDF file is sent to this function in `bytes[]`, then I create `pdfReader` from this...

From `pdfReader` I create `pdfStamper` (i.e. new PDF file) and write the response values to  its fields. It is working fine... only issue is `fint` size of values is much large...

```
public void GeneratePrintPDFTest(ResponseGroup actual, Pages page, byte[] filebyte, out string pdfname, string localstorage)
{
   string rootPath = @"D:/FOP-PDF/";
   var pdfReader = new PdfReader(filebyte);
   var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,new FileStream(rootPath.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + page.PageId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    + ".pdf",FileMode.Create));
   pdfname = rootPath.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + page.PageId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".pdf";

   AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

   foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
   {
       var response = actual.Responses.Where(obj => obj.ITPPageFieldKeyId == Convert.ToInt32(de.Key.ToString())).Select(obj => obj).FirstOrDefault();

       if (response != null)
       {
           if (response.ResponseValues != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ResponseValues.ToString())
                        && response.ResponseValues.ToString() != "0" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.DataItemID)
                        && response.DataItemID != "0")
           {
              if (response.PrintFormulaResult || response.PageFieldFormulaId == 0)
              {
                 pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), response.ResponseValues.ToString());
              }
           }
        }
     }

     pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
     pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

I tried following solutions but of no use....

```
float fSize = 10;
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), de.Key.ToString(), fSize, null);
```

I also doubt it may be coming from the template PDF file, but if so how could I change it programatically.

Please help me with this... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you use chunks instead of the Responsevalue.tostring? The Font-size of chunks can be controlled.